# Does Jprofiler analyze gc log files to show things like eden space utilization vs tenured utilization etc.?

Tags: jprofiler

JClarity claims to be able to analyze gc log files to show such interesting & useful facts such as eden space utilization over time etc. This could help me, presumably, tune my GC settings etc. But, I already bought jprofiler. Does jprofiler provide similar functionality? (I couldn't find any tutorial or examples that would allow me to do similar things to jclarity, such as showing eden space utilization over time etc.)

Answer (score 0):

As of version 10.1, JProfiler does not analyze GC log files. However, the "Memory" VM telemetry can show all the memory pools separately. You can select a memory pool in the drop-down at the top.